# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can I get better performance on Raspbian if I blacklist a lot of kernel modules in raspi-blacklist.conf?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26853/can-i-get-better-performance-on-raspbian-if-i-blacklist-a-lot-of-kernel-modules)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Problems with installing Node.js NPM package](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27333/problems-with-installing-nodejs-npm-package)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How is Raspberry Pi "open source" if it uses ARM?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/how-is-raspberry-pi-open-source-if-it-uses-arm)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [kodi (xbmc) on raspbian can't activate keyboard or mouse](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27077/kodi-xbmc-on-raspbian-cant-activate-keyboard-or-mouse)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [GPIO general use pins stuck in HIGH position](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27013/gpio-general-use-pins-stuck-in-high-position)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Sampling on the Pi using MCP3004](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27388/sampling-on-the-pi-using-mcp3004)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Which addressable RGB LED strips are beginner friendly and Raspberry Pi friendly?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26730/which-addressable-rgb-led-strips-are-beginner-friendly-and-raspberry-pi-friendly)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Raspberry pi 2 1024M Increase Gpu Memory to 512 at least](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/raspberry-pi-2-1024m-increase-gpu-memory-to-512-at-least)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [GPIO Temperature Sensor not Recognized](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26944/gpio-temperature-sensor-not-recognized)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Raspberry Python Libraries](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27334/raspberry-python-libraries)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 10)

---

Answer (score 3):

>.<

Those numbers aren't pretty.

Obviously, it could be worse, but 4/10 of your questions with a negative score...either we were being exceptionally nice with the past self-evaluation, or our quality has declined.

I sure hope it's not the second case D:

Comment: I was actually surprised at the quality of the Q&As (there's a backhanded compliment...) and the "self-evaluation" seems a bit harsh.   I think in general we have a tough crowd to please, lol, or put another way, we lack "critical positive mass".   It's also a tough niche, since we overlap so much with other more general S.E. sites (U&L, E.E., S.O.), and a lot of what's left over is often very hard to reproduce ("It should work but it doesn't, why?") and solve satisfactorily.  Some of those questions should have been closed in the first place...

Comment: ...E.g. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27334/raspberry-python-libraries <- Which got the worst score, is too broad and opinion oriented.   But since there is at least an upvoted answer at this point it might as well remain open.

Comment: @goldilocks This is true. We have a very good community that usually produces good answers - I wish I knew more so I could be more involved :P As you said, we overlap quite a bit. It makes us look quite a bit less impressive, but I think we still serve a useful purpose. Here's to the future of RPi.SE! :D Also. If you need my help with stuff (flagging, editing, and certain stuff to watch for - let me know. I'll do my best to help as possible with my limited privelidges!